# Python: Find combination of keywords in text

Tags: python, string, search, nlp

I am using the following function to determine if a text has words (or expressions) from a list:

```
def is_in_text(text, lista=[]):
    return any(i in text for i in lista)
```

I can pass to this function a list of words and expressions that I would like to find in a text. For example, the following code:

```
text_a = 'There are white clouds in the sky'
print(is_in_text(text_a, ['clouds in the sky']))
```

Will return

```
True
```

This works if I'm interested in texts that mention "clouds" and "sky". However, if the text varies slightly, I may no longer detect it. For example:

```
text_b = 'There are white clouds in the beautiful sky'
print(is_in_text(text_b, ['clouds in the sky']))
```

Will return False.

How can I modify this function to be able to find texts that contain both words, but not necessarily in a predetermined order? In this example, I would like to look for "'clouds' + 'sky' ".

Just to be clear, I am interested in texts that contain both words. I would like to have a function that searchs for these kind of combinations, without me having to enter all these conditions manually.

Comment: An advice: you should preprocess text with stemming and removing stopword. Those are common approaches in NLP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-write `is_in_text` to check that each word in whatever list of words you want to check is in the string:

```
def is_in_text(text, lista=[]):
    isin = True
    for word in lista:
        isin = isin and (word in text)
    return isin
```

E.g.

```
text_a = 'There are white clouds in the sky'
print(is_in_text(text_a, ['cloud', 'sky']))
```

returns `True`

while

```
text_a = 'There are white clouds in the sky'
print(is_in_text(text_a, ['dog', 'sky']))
```

returns `False`

This requires you to know what words you want to match the two strings on, though. If you want to check all the words in your string you can split your string on spaces.

E.g.

```
text_b = 'There are white clouds in the beautiful sky'
print(is_in_text(text_b, 'clouds in the sky'.split(' ')))
```

now returns `True`

#### Edit:

So, I think you should probably re-think what you're trying to do since this will be pretty fragile, but based on what you're describing this works:

```
def is_in_text(text, lista=[]):
    isin = False
    for string in lista:
        sub_isin = True
        for substr in string.split(' '):
            sub_isin = sub_isin & (substr in text)

        isin = isin or sub_isin
    return isin
```

E.g.

```
text_a = 'There are white clouds in the sky'
print(is_in_text(text_a, ['rain', 'cloud sky']))
```

evaluates to `True`

while

```
text_a = 'There are white clouds in the sky'
print(is_in_text(text_a, ['rain', 'dog sky']))
```

evaluates to `False`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is that I don't necessarily want to search for texts that contain **all** the words in the list. For example, I wish I could pass this list:


weather_topics = ['rain', '"clouds" + "sky"', 'storm']


And the function ideally should return True if rain _or_ storm _or_ (clouds _and_ sky) are in the text.

Comment: if you have some words that are required and some that are optional I would write a function that takes two kwargs, `optional` and `required`. Other solutions would be more opaque I think

Comment: All the elements of the list are optional, just that some of them are just _a)_ one word/expression and the others are _b)_ combinations of words/expressions. Currently, I am only able to detect the _a)_ elements

Comment: but for the ones that are combinations of words/expression do you want to check that that substring (e.g. `clouds and sky`) occurs as that substring explicitly, or just that both `clouds` and `sky` need to both be in the string you're evaluating for the expression to be `True`?

Comment: The second, both words need to be in the string.

Comment: check my edit. again, it would likely be better to be more explicit by having e.g. kwargs `single` and `combinations` where you specify two different lists, where combinations would be nested (e.g. `[('cloud', 'sky')] `that you would then iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this might be to first convert your text into a list e.g.

```
a = ["white", "clouds"]
```

Then have your keywords list:

```
b = ["clouds", "red"]
```

Then do:

```
set(a).intersection(b)
```

which returns:

```
{'clouds'}
```